# How to define a function in a HighVoltage static pages controller for show action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, static-pages, high-voltage

I use HighVoltage for static pages. I have:

```
get "/filter/:city" => 'pages#show', as: :page, format: false
root to: 'pages#show', id: 'home', :defaults => { :city => "Bolu" }
```

in the routes.rb.

I have a PagesController:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  include HighVoltage::StaticPage
end
```

Now, I have a home.html.erb for the homepage. I wanted define some things in the controller. For example, I want:

```
@events = Event.where(name: "sports")
```

so I tried to write

```
def show
end
```

in the PagesController but is gives "No such page: home". I'm a bit lost here. Any suggestion?